# Não consigo gravar no banco de dados PHP

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

O arquivo 1 pega os dados para inserir no banco de dados, o nome e email estão corretamente sendo gravados, mas o telefone não vai para o banco.

ARQUIVO 1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validar()
    {
        var nome = formulario.nome.value;

        // valida nome
        if (nome == "")
        {
            alert('Preencha o nome da pessoa!');
            formulario.nome.focus();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
</script>




<form action="pessoas_incluir.php" method="POST" name="formulario" >

    <label>Nome da Pessoa </label>
    <input type="text" name="nome" value="" size="40" maxlength="40" required onblur="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" autofocus>
    <br><br>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" size="40" maxlength="40" required>
    <br><br>
    <label>Telefone</label>
    <input type="text" name="fone" value="" size="15" maxlength="14" required>
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit" onClick="return validar()">Salvar</button>
    <button type="reset">Limpar</button>
</form>
```

ARQUIVO pessoas_incluir.php

```
<?php
 include_once "../conexao.php"; 

    $conn = mysqli_connect($localhost, $user, $password, $banco);

    if (!$conn)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Não foi possível conectar ao Banco de Dados!');</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        // recebe parametro
        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $fone = $POST['fone'];

        // monta QUERY
        $sql = "INSERT INTO PESSOAS (Nome, Email, Telefone) VALUES ('$nome','$email','$fone')";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (! $result)
        {
            echo  "Erro na inclusão dos dados!";
        }
        else
        {
            echo  "Dados incluídos com sucesso!";
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
    header("Location: pessoas_mostra.php");
?>
```

Comment: Lucas precisamos de mais detalhes para poder oferecer-lhe uma resposta.

Comment: o que é isso aqui? `onClick="return validar()"`

Comment: PS: O Texto da pergunta e [formatado com markdown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: É pra validar se foi digitado algo ou n

Comment: PS: Sou iniciante

Comment: Apresenta mensagem de erro, comportamento estranho ou há alguma coisa a mais que queira comentar? Normalmente quem responde PHP cliente/servidor  faz teste de mesa é um trabalho totalmente humano, quanto mais informação sobre os comportamentos do programa e logs melhor para responder.

Comment: Nao aponta nenhum erro, simplesmente o conteúdo do input cujo name="fone" não grava no banco, o resto do código está funcionando perfeitamente.

Comment: Talvez seja algum bug

Comment: Por isso que, a cima, pedi que coloca-se na pergunta o código de `validar()`.A maioria dos erros trazidos aqui ocorrem durante a validação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fone = $POST['fone'];
```

nesta linha, substitui por

```
$fone = $_POST['fone'];
```

Faltou o UNDERLINE da SUPERGLOBAL $_POST[]

Comment: puts, muito obrigado, agora deu certo!!